# How to save icon color in hive flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a favorite button for my app. Which work is to change and save color, while the user presses it,So I decided to use hive db for it.When the icon button is tapped; the color get changed,which indicates the user that its been marked as their favorite.The problem is when i tap it again(if the user wants to unmark it ) though the color get changed ,when i move to other page or hot start/reload the page, the color changed back to it former self automatically(To the color when it was first pressed).I wants the color reactive through the button and be saved.How can i solve this issue?

```
class p1 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_p1State createState() => _p1State();
}

class _p1State extends State<p1> {
Box box;
bool _isFavorite = false;

_p1State();
@override
void initstate(){
 super.initState();
// Get reference to an already opened box

box = Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX);
final data = box.get(_isFavorite);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
   body:Stack(
       children:<Widget>[
       Image(
       image:AssetImage("Image/Chowsun1.jpg"),
     fit:BoxFit.cover,
     width: double.infinity,
     height: double.infinity,
    ),
      Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(' Rehman '
              ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: "Explora",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900 ) )



      ),
         Stack ( children: [Positioned(
           top:90,
           right: 20,
           child:const Text('   1 ',
             style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 25.0,
                 color: Colors.white,
                 fontFamily: "Comforter"
             ),
           ),
         )], ),





    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: (
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.favorite,
                    color:_isFavorite ? Colors.white: Colors.red


                ),

                onPressed: () {

                  setState(() {
                    _isFavorite= !_isFavorite;
                  });

                  box.put(1, _isFavorite);



                }

            )
        )
    )])

  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Hive.box('your_Hive_DB_Name').containsKey(
"Key" ? Colors.red: Colors.white)
```

Comment: it says error: A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Box<dynamic>'.

Comment: did you replace my answer in your Code? if `yes` then make sure you're good with your codes logic if not i update my answer to a working code, plus you simply put a `bool` value into your box which is either true or false, try for a `string`.

Comment: box = Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX).containsKey(Key != null ?  Colors.white: Colors.red )  as 
 Box;
    final data = box.get(_isFavorite);   i did this way.

Comment: you don't have to do `as box` just put the `key` in it, in your case it's number `1`.